# How to remove the dismiss keyboard action on tapping outside MDCTextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, material-design, mdc-components

I am trying to use an [MDCTextField](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/textfields/) and a table view together. The `MDCTextField` filters the table view, then the user should tap a cell and the keyboard should dismiss and the table view should be hidden. The issue is that the keyboard dismisses and the table view is hidden before the table view registers that a cell was tapped. How can I register that a cell was tapped before the `MDCTextField` registers the tap?

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension you can place in a helpers.swift file but this way you can use on any UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
        func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
            let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
            tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }

        @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

To use it, on viewDidLoad() just add this `self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()`

**EDIT Based on comment**

In theory the following code should help, but I haven't got around to test it, I've read that people couldn't get the touchBegan function to trigger but I also don't know any other way to do what you want.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: view)
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: position) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: ip)
            print(cell.text)
        }
    }
}
```

The theory is the following

First we get the position where the tap occurred then we get the IndexPath for the row witch was taped (if exists) as we have the IndexPath we just get the cell.

In the example I gave you I print the cell text, but you can do any other operation that you want

I hope this is what you want and you can get it to work as I did not got around to test it and seems that some people are getting problems triggering the touchesBegan function

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. The keyboard dismisses before a table view cell is selected. I'm trying to have the table view tap register first. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @jimmyruby I misunderstood your question, I think the update fits your needs. I will however leave the previous part has it can help other users